# python string import doesn't work

Tags: python-3.6

post#1 Learning python.

Using IDLE shell and script, both experience this issue.

Successfully importing "string" module, but calling a function from it returns an error:

```
from string import *
find("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat","atg")
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    find("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat","atgc")
NameError: name 'find' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find is a method of the class string.  You have to use `.find`

try below example:

```
str1 = "atgacatgcacaagtatgcat"

str2 = "atg"

str1.find(str2)
```